# Why are some css elements not working on iphones?

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with some css elements that are breaking on iphone browsers (safari & chrome) when it's working totally fine on desktop and android devices.

I've attached 2 images of the sign in screens as one of the examples, the code for this screen is as follows:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gidole Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gidole Regular'), url('../fonts/Gidole-Regular.woff') format('woff');
    }

body {
    max-width: 1920px;
    max-height: 1920px;
    background: #eee;
}



.Title {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-family: industry-inc-3d, sans-serif;
    height: 128px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f05d5b;
}

.flashed-messages
{
    font-family: industry-inc-3d, sans-serif;
    height: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f05d5b;
    /* border: 1.5px solid #f05d5b;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #f05d5b;
    margin-top: 10px; */
}


.form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}

.email-box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f6f7f7;
    border: 1.5px solid #f05d5b;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #f05d5b;
    position: relative;
}

.email {
    width: 299px;
    height: 24px;
    font-family: industry-inc-base, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #707070;
}

.password-box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f6f7f7;
    border: 1.5px solid #f05d5b;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #f05d5b;
    position: center;

}

.password {
    width: 299px;
    height: 24px;
    font-family: industry-inc-base, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #707070;
}

.button-signin {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 143px;
    height: 27px;
    font-family: industry-inc-3d, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f05d5b;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f6f7f7;
    border: 1.5px solid #f05d5b;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #f05d5b;
}

.button {
    text-align: center;
}

.signup-text{
    font-family: "Gidole Regular";
    width: 218px;
    height: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #707070;
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

}

.signup-link{
    font-family: "Gidole Regular";
    width: 218px;
    height: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #707070;
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

}

.signup {
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Sign in</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/sign_in.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/sign_in.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="precious.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/oaq5uou.css">
    <style>
        @import url("https://use.typekit.net/oaq5uou.css");
      </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 class="Title">Welcome To Precious</h1>
    <div class="flashed-messages">
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
            {% if messages %}
                {% for message in messages %}
                    {{ message }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    </div>
    <div class="form">
        <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
            <div>
                <div><label class="email" for="email">Email</label></div>
                <div><input class="email-box" type="email" name="email"></div>
            </div>
                <br>
            <div>
                <div><label class="password" for="password">Password</label></div>
                <div><input class="password-box" type="password" name="password"></div>
            </div>
                <br>
            <div class="button">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" class="button-signin" >
            </div>
        </form>

       

        <div class="signup">
            <a class="signup-text">No account? </a>
            <a href="/sign_up" class="signup-link">sign up</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Dektop or adroid browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3YFD.png)

[Iphone browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSHMW.jpg)

Anyone has an idea why that could be happening?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It happens because browsers apply some default styling. You can reset/overwrite this styling.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of how the elements are exactly breaking on iPhone?
I noticed that you are setting fixed height on the title and message - this could be your problem with things getting too compressed and even overlapping. Use margin-bottom instead to define the space between your elements. Height is appropriate primary for images, but not dynamic content as text.

Comment: Needed to overwrite some default styling. Would love to learn why iphone do that in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers add their own styling for form elements. You need to remove it by using:

```
.thing {
   -webkit-appearance: value;
   -moz-appearance:    value;
   appearance:         value;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need prefixer.

Here is a good website:

https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Copy / Paste your code into the formatter and copy the formatted CSS code.

Try this CSS code:

```
/*
* Prefixed by https://autoprefixer.github.io
* PostCSS: v7.0.29,
* Autoprefixer: v9.7.6
* Browsers: last 4 version
*/

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gidole Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gidole Regular'), url('../fonts/Gidole-Regular.woff') format('woff');
    }

body {
    max-width: 1920px;
    max-height: 1920px;
    background: #eee;
}



.Title {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-family: industry-inc-3d, sans-serif;
    height: 128px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f05d5b;
}

.flashed-messages
{
    font-family: industry-inc-3d, sans-serif;
    height: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f05d5b;
    /* border: 1.5px solid #f05d5b;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #f05d5b;
    margin-top: 10px; */
}


.form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}

.email-box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f6f7f7;
    border: 1.5px solid #f05d5b;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #f05d5b;
            box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #f05d5b;
    position: relative;
}

.email {
    width: 299px;
    height: 24px;
    font-family: industry-inc-base, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #707070;
}

.password-box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f6f7f7;
    border: 1.5px solid #f05d5b;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #f05d5b;
            box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #f05d5b;
    position: center;

}

.password {
    width: 299px;
    height: 24px;
    font-family: industry-inc-base, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #707070;
}

.button-signin {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 143px;
    height: 27px;
    font-family: industry-inc-3d, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f05d5b;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f6f7f7;
    border: 1.5px solid #f05d5b;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #f05d5b;
            box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #f05d5b;
}

.button {
    text-align: center;
}

.signup-text{
    font-family: "Gidole Regular";
    width: 218px;
    height: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #707070;
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

}

.signup-link{
    font-family: "Gidole Regular";
    width: 218px;
    height: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #707070;
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

}

.signup {
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ifaruki. The issues were fixed by overwriting for default appearances. Works fine now. Thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, Maher.

Try removing the height properties on on `Title` and `flashed-messages`. On Small screens the copy will break on multiple lines but the height is still the same. In this case the text will overlap with the content from bellow. You might experience this only on iPhone if the particular device you use has smaller screen width than the Android you use.